# Get outline coordinates of a font glyph in Python

Tags: python, bezier, glyph, ttx-fonttools

I need to extract regular spaced boundary coordinates of glyphs from an OTF file in order to draw them (approximated) as a shape consisting of straight segments. That is, for a given string `'draft'` I want to read the corresponding glyphs from the OTF file (if possible, using ligatures when appropriate) and calculate their outline coordinates (say with a font size of 100 units and a coordinate spacing of about 1 unit) in order to draw them in a context where I can only draw shapes consisting of straight lines. I need to do all of this using Python (though calling external command line tools would certainly be okay).

After searching around a bit online, my impression is that I should be able to get there (or almost there) using `fontTools`, but I'm having trouble finding what I need in [the documentation](https://fonttools.readthedocs.io/). It is quite long and does not contain a lot of examples, which makes it difficult for me to determine if it has what I need.

- Is `fontTools` the tool for me? If not, is there a Python library I can use instead?
- How can I read the correct glyphs from the OTF file?
- How can I interpolate between the control points of the glyphs?

Answer (score 2):

yes fontTools is perfect for you!

If you have an `OTF` file you find find the drawing in `CFF`  or `CFF2` table.
I recommend running `ttx font.otf` and inspect outputted `xml` file to understand the structure.

You `cff` table will probably be subroutinized. This means that parts of the contour are saved as "elements" and used across the fonts to save some weight. This replaces components known from `TrueType` fonts. Just run `subroutinize` method on the `CFF` table and you should be able to read everything you need.

### A snippet replacing every glyph in list named `keep_g_names`

```
    def process_cff(self) -> None:
        cff = self.font["CFF "]
        cmap_reversed = {v: k for k, v in self.font.getBestCmap().items()}

        if hasattr(cff, "desubroutinize"):
            cff.desubroutinize()

        content = cff.cff[cff.cff.keys()[0]]  # can it have more fonts?

        for key in content.CharStrings.keys():
            if key in self.keep_g_names:
                continue
            content.CharStrings[key] = content.CharStrings["n"]
```

Does this help you?

What do you mean by `How can I interpolate between the control points of the glyphs?`